# c++ same code compiles/runs never in Visual Studio and sometimes in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, qt-creator

I was making some of my c++ exercises when I noticed following problem.
The given code will not run/compile in Visual Studio 2013 or Qt Creator 5.4.1

giving the error:

```
invalid types 'double[int]' for array subscript
test[0][0] = 2;
         ^
```

However when you first change the 16th (and 17th) line in the header file from
`double &operator[];` to `double operator[]` and make the same changes in the source files -> then compile this (while getting multiple errors) -> and lastly changing it back to the original `double &operator[];`. Then in Qt Creator 5.4.1 it will compile and it will run while giving the expected results.

Edit: This does not always work, however changing it to `double *operator[]` instead of `double operator[]` will always reproduce the problem.

Why is this happening?

matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
private:
    double** m_elements;
    int m_rows;
    int m_columns;
public:
    Matrix(int rows = 1, int columns = 1);
    double &operator[](int index);
    const double &operator[](int index) const;
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &ostr, Matrix matrix);
};

#endif // MATRIX_H
```

matrix.cpp

```
#include "matrix.h"

Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int columns)
{
    m_rows = rows;
    m_columns = columns;
    m_elements = new double*[rows];
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        m_elements[i] = new double[columns];
        for(int j=0; j<columns; j++)
            m_elements[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

double &Matrix::operator[](int index)
{
    return *(m_elements[index]);
}

const double &Matrix::operator[](int index) const
{
    return *(m_elements[index]);
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &ostr, Matrix matrix)
{
    for(int i=0; i<matrix.m_rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<matrix.m_columns; j++)
        {
            ostr << matrix.m_elements[i][j] << " ";
        }
        ostr << "\n";
    }
    return ostr;
}
```

main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Matrix test(4,4);
    test[0][0] = 2;
    cout << test;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have been doing this for decades, but would never dare to write `*m_elements[index];`. Do YOU know if `*` or `[]` is applied first? I don't! :-)  I would write either `*(m_elements[index]);` or `(*m_elements)[index];` depending on the order intended.

Comment: Thanks for the tip (it did used `*(m_elements[index]);` as I expected but maybe on a different compiler this won't be the case), I edited my file, but this still does not fix the problem I have.

Comment: I'm fairly sure returning a reference-to-douible from `operator[]` isn't what you want to do regardless. if `operator[]` is supposed to deliver the base of a *row* in your matrix, you should be returning simply `m_elements[index]` with a return type of `double*`, or `double *&` if you actually want to reference the pointer at `m_elements[index]` directly (which I don't advise).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double &Matrix::operator[](int index)
{
    return *(m_elements[index]);
}
```

Will return a reference to the first element in the column rather than the column. So calling `test[0][0] = 2;` tries to apply the `[]` operator to a double, not an array of double.

Quick solution:

```
double * & Matrix::operator[](size_t index)
{
    return m_elements[index];
}
```

This returns a reference to a pointer (read on to find out why I bother with the reference) and you can use [] on the returned pointer to get to the data element.

## But...

There are better ways to do this.

Use std::vector, if possible, instead of the dynamic array.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > m_elements(m_rows, std::vector<double>(m_columns, 0.0));
```

This will solve a lot of potential problems and does the initializing of the matrix to 0 in one shot. It won't solve the [][] indexing though. That will still take a bit of work.

The simplest and safest way to do the indexing is to not use the [] operator at all. Instead define a new method. This way you have total control over what is exposed, and the input can be completely tested for validity before running out of bounds.

```
double &Matrix::at(size_t row, size_t column) 
{
    // optional overrun defence if desired
    if (row < m_rows || column < m_columns)
    {
        return m_elements[row][column]; 
    } 
    throw std::out_of_range("Matrix indices out of range");
}
double Matrix::at(size_t row, size_t column) const
{
    // put overrun defence here if desired
    return m_elements[row][column]; 
}
matrix.at(2,3) = 2;
constmatrix.at(2,3) = 2; // bad lvalue compiler error
```

Note the use of `size_t` in place of `int`. size_t is unsigned and removes the need to validity check for negative numbers. You can't have a negative array index, so why allow the possibility?

It is also worth noting that this approach makes it easy to define storage for your matrix as a 1 dimensional array like this:

```
std::vector<double> m_elements(m_rows * m_columns, 0.0);
```

or if you have to use an array

```
double m_elements = new double[m_rows* m_columns];
```

and access it like this:

```
double &Matrix::at(size_t row, size_t column) 
{
    return m_elements[row * m_rows + column]; 
}
```

Why? A number of good reasons. Easier to create, maintain and clean up one object than m_rows +1 is a good enough reason for me. Another excellent reason is locality. The whole matrix is guaranteed to be in one contiguous block, not one array here, another there, and yet another in the RAM equivalent of the bottom of the Marianas Trench. The odds of cache hits (and thus performance) go way up.

If you prefer the look and feel of an array, an operator() overload comes quite close.

```
double &Matrix::operator()(size_t row, size_t column) 
{
    return m_elements[row][column];
 }
double Matrix::operator()(size_t row, size_t column) const
{
    return m_elements[row][column];
}
matrix(2,3) = 2;
```

## If you must have [][]

The suggested form of an [] operator returns a reference to the  indexed data, in this case a vector or a pointer to a row array.

```
std::vector<double> & Matrix::operator[](size_t index)
{
    return m_elements[index];
}
```

or

```
double * & Matrix::operator[](size_t index)
```

The array and vector internals are identical.

Caveat: This allows the user to get up to all sorts of trouble with that returned vector or pointer reference. Consider `matrix[0].clear();` or `matrix[0] = NULL;` for example.

```
double * Matrix::operator[](size_t index)
```

will prevent most abuse by returning a copy of the pointer. Unfortunately this cannot be done to protect the vector because a copy of the vector will be a completely different vector with copies of the source's contents. Updating it and expecting persistence would be futile. The vector would have to be hidden from the user inside a wrapper class, and this is rapidly becoming too much work.

In addition, returning the copy or a wrapper will also block legitimate uses of a reference and violates the Law of Least Surprise: The Matrix [] operator does not work the same as other [] operators and may result in unexpected behaviour if an unsuspecting coder uses it as a regular [] operator.

My opinion is return the unprotected references, and if whoever is using the Matrix class wants to shoot themselves in the head... Well, you can only do so much. If you have to protect the user, use the `at` method or `operator()` approach described above.

Const [] operators are similar for the vector

```
std::vector<double> const & Matrix::operator[](size_t index) const
```

but different for the array because both the pointer and the values pointed at should be const

```
double const * const & Matrix::operator[](size_t index) const
```

My suggested implementation:

Matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// note that the using namespace std; is gone. One should never put it in the header
// and one should also think hard about putting it in the implementation file
class Matrix
{
private:
    std::vector<double> m_elements;
    size_t m_rows;
    size_t m_columns;
public:
    Matrix(int rows = 1, int columns = 1);

    double &operator()(size_t row, size_t column);

    double operator()(size_t row, size_t column) const;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &ostr, const Matrix & matrix);
};

#endif // MATRIX_H
```

Matrix.cpp

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Matrix.h"

Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int columns):
        m_elements(rows * columns, 0.0),
        m_rows(rows),
        m_columns(columns)
{
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &ostr, const Matrix &matrix)
{
    for(size_t i=0; i<matrix.m_rows; i++)
    {
        for(size_t j=0; j<matrix.m_columns; j++)
        {
            ostr << matrix(i,j) << " ";
        }
        ostr << std::endl;
    }
    return ostr;
}

double &Matrix::operator()(size_t row, size_t column)
{
    if (row < m_rows && column < m_columns)
    {
        return m_elements[row * m_rows + column];
    }
    throw std::out_of_range("Matrix indices out of range");
 }

double Matrix::operator()(size_t row, size_t column) const
{
    if (row < m_rows && column < m_columns)
    {
        return m_elements[row * m_rows + column];
    }
    throw std::out_of_range("Matrix indices out of range");
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to return a reference, and it allows strange things like `test[0]++` (increment the pointer to the first row) which may lead to UB. Also a reference to a const pointer is not meaningless.

Comment: @Oktalist This is me being lazy. I didn't want to try and explain the type safety issues behind the compiler warnings from returning a const pointer reference and I didn't even consider the downside of returning a non const reference in the non const version.

Comment: This answer is a mess, perhaps you could rewrite it to give concrete , correct advice

Answer (score 0):

Just Because of the Meaning of the Return.

When You return Reference `&`, you could change it as you wanna, like `test[2][2] = 2;`Because it will make mean back to the source it had ever refer to

When You return By value, It just a temporary Object which will be destroyed after using, that means, You Could Not Change It !